# header and footer not displayed in Kendo UI Mobile PhoneGap Application For Android

Tags: android, cordova, kendo-ui

I created a phonegap application for android using Kendo UI. Here, the problem is.. header and footer not displayed in android device. It was working fine on IOS device and Normal browsers.
Check this link: http://demos.kendoui.com/mobile/application/index.html

From above link, they displayed the o/p on ios and android with same code. In IOS header was displayed fine, but not in android device. But, I want to display the header with back button using Kendo UI for android.. How can I do this.. Any other ways...

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Find out the solution from this link: http://www.kendoui.com/forums/mobile/navbar/android-switch-header-and-footer.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Additionally to show the title, use the CSS outlined in [Kendo UI Doc.](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/navbar#showing-hidden-view-title)